# Mule:Change from version 3.8.3 to 3.7.2 introduces new errors

Tags: mule

I developed my simple app on mule 3.8.3 , however I need to run it on 3.7.2. After I changed my 'mule-project.xml' & pom.xml , in which I had to comment out the dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-apikit</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

which enabled me to run my code on anypoint platform, however I ran into another error which is:

```
    Caused by: org.mule.mvel2.PropertyAccessException: [Error: unable      to resolve method: java.io.IOException.getSummaryMessage() [arglength=0]]
```

[Near : {... exception.getSummaryMessage() ....}]
             ^
        [Line: 1, Column: 1]
        at          org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.getMethod(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:1173) ~[mule-mvel2-2.1.9-MULE-007.jar:?]
    at org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.getMethod(ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.java:1082) ~[mule-mvel2-2.1.9-MULE-007.jar:?]
    at org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.ReflectiveAccessorOptimizer.compileGetChain(ReflectiveAccessorOptim

And I realize it is because I have the following catch exceptions strategy:

```
      <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <set-payload value="The request cannot be processed, the error is #[exception.getSummaryMessage()]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
         </catch-exception-strategy>
```

It does not like 'getSummaryMessage' what is the alternative to that on this version? & any other general pointers when downgrading versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading version is not advisable as you are missing out on various fixed bugs, patches, newly added features and enhancements.

For issue with your error message, try any of below.

```
#[exception.getMessageCode()]
#[exception.getVerboseMessage()]
#[exception.getDetailedMessage()]
#[exception.getExceptionCode()]
```